# MOSS SSP and asp.net membership database

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-membership, ssp

We have MOSS configured to use the asp.net membership database and now want to configure our Shared Services Provider to import or use the information in our aspnet membership database.

We only see LDAP and BDC as import options though, can anyone suggest how best to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint MOSS, out of the box supports only the User Profiles from the Active Directory.In your case of user details in the separate FBA DB you will have to write a Custom Code to pull the information from the DB.

In one of our project we have been doing a import using the coding.

```
UserProfile profile = userProfileManager.CreateUserProfile("Provider name:username")
```

Refer the following links for more details

1. [Complete Details on FBA](http://www.sharepointfba.com/)
2. [Example code snippet to create a User Profile in Code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/archive/2008/08/01/fba-in-sharepoint-everything-you-ve-ever-wanted-to-do-continued.aspx)

Comment: We found this to be very useful http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sptoolbox&ReleaseId=8728